# Trying to define an abstract notion of a function that turns sets of sentences into the set of models satisfying those sentences.

Tags: model-theory

Let $\mathsf{Sen}$ denote a Boolean algebra, thought of as a collection of sentences, and let $\mathsf{Mod}$ denote a set without any additional structure, thought of as a collection of models. I'm trying to define (abstractly) the notion that a function $f : \mathcal{P}(\mathsf{Sen}) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathsf{Mod})$ turns a set of sentences $A \in \mathcal{P}(\mathsf{Sen})$ into the set of all models satisfying those sentences $f(A) \in \mathcal{P}(\mathsf{Mod})$.

Now its clear that $f$ ought to turn arbitrary unions into intersections. That is, for all $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\mathsf{Sen})$ we require that $$f(\bigcup_{A \in \mathcal{A}} A) = \bigcap_{A \in \mathcal{A}}f(A).$$

**So my first question is**: going on our intuition involving first/second-order logic and first/second-order models, ought we require that $f$ turn arbitrary intersections into unions? And should we require that $f$ interact nicely with complements?

Now furthermore, $f$ ought to be compatible with the Boolean Algebra structure on $\mathsf{Sen}$. For instance, if $\phi,\psi \in \mathsf{Sen},$ then we want $$f(\{\phi \wedge \psi\}) = f(\{\phi\}) \cap f(\{\psi\}),\quad f(\{\phi \vee \psi\}) = f(\{\phi\}) \cup f(\{\psi\}),\quad f(\{\phi^c\}) = \mathsf{Mod} \setminus f(\{\phi\})$$

**My second question is**: Are the requirements of the above paragraph sufficient, given that they're only written in terms of singleton sets, when after all $f$ can potentially operate on infinite collections of sentences? Again, let us go with the intuition that comes from thinking about first/second-order logic and first/second-order models.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f$ is a [Galois connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_connection) between the poset of sets of sentences and the poset of sets of models. Here is a general way to induce Galois connections between such posets: let $X, Y$ be sets and let $R \subseteq X \times Y$ be a relation, which we will write $xRy$. Then we get a Galois connection between the poset of subsets of $X$ and the poset of subsets of $Y$ given by the functions

$$f(S) = \{ y : xRy \forall x \in S \}$$

where $S \subseteq X$ and $f(S) \subseteq Y$, and

$$g(T) = \{ x : xRy \forall y \in T \}$$

where $T \subseteq Y$ and $g(T) \subseteq X$. We recover several classical examples of Galois connections this way.

- The motivating example behind the name: let $L/K$ be a Galois extension, let $X = K$, and let $Y = \text{Gal}(L/K)$. The relation is $xRy$ iff the group element $y$ fixes the element $x$. This induces the Galois connection between subextensions of $L/K$ and subgroups of $Y$ which is the subject of the [fundamental theorem of Galois theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Galois_theory)
- Let $X = k[x_1, ... x_n]$ ($k$ an algebraically closed field) and let $Y = k^n$. The relation is $xRy$ iff the function $x$ vanishes on the point $y$. This induces the Galois connection between ideals of $k[x_1, ... x_n]$ and subvarieties of $k^n$ which is the subject of the [Nullstellensatz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Nullstellensatz).
- In this case, let $X$ be the set of sentences and let $Y$ be the set of models. The relation is $xRy$ iff the sentence $x$ is true in the model $y$. This induces the Galois connection between sets of sentences and sets of models which is the subject of the [completeness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem) (in first-order logic).

I think it was Lawvere who first noticed this. The slogan is "syntax is [adjoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_functors) to semantics." Connecting the last two examples together, you can think of sentences as functions on the space of models and taking the set of models satisfying a collection of sentences as taking the subspace on which a collection of functions vanishes.

Comment: This is one of the better pieces of evidence I know of for arguing that you should study a broad range of mathematics. It's not at all obvious that learning Galois theory or algebraic geometry would help you understand a construction in model theory, but the same patterns recur throughout mathematics and learning them in one context is a good way to spot them in another.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I'll have a ponder over it and get back to you if there's need for clarification. Basically, what I'm seeing is that $f(S)$ is the set of all models that satisfy every axiom in $S$, and $g(T)$ is the set of all sentences that are satisfied by every structure in $T$. So I think that $g(\{y\})$ is the complete theory of $y$, no?

Comment: @user: yes, that's it.